# How to let raspberry pi know if switch on switch board on or off

Tags: pi-2, home-automation

Scenario is as follows:

I have an electric switch board, they control bulbs and fans in my room. I have created a system already to control bulbs and fans with relay switch.
Now my aim is when I switch on via traditional electric switch, raspberry pi should know that it has been switched on.

I would like to know how I can do this.

Comment: I don't have an answer either way, but I suspect it is much simpler if some wiring from the live circuit controlled by the switch can be connected to something connected to the pi.  So you might want to mention whether that is the case or not.  Of course, if a relay connected to the pi potentially feeds the outputs (fans and lights) of the same circuit, then there is probably already such a wire available...

Comment: Modify your circuit so that voltage is sent to a GPIO pin when one of your switches are flipped, then write a little program that monitors the pins (as input pins).

Comment: I thought of that, I am new to electronics and electrical, I am not sure how to do that is there an ic I have to use

Comment: @tlhIngan I think the question here is largely about *how* to downstep 120V (or 220V, or whatever) to 3.3V ;)  I guess a giant resistor could work, but it is going to give off a lot of heat and waste a correspond amount of energy.  Presumably there is some better option.

Comment: I read about that can be done via an opto-coupler, please correct me if this is wrong

Comment: I think you are right, that's what's used in a lot of relays.  We need to wait for someone in know to come along, lol -- or you could focus on that, generalize the question, and ask on our larger sibling site, [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).  They will likely quickly close it as having already been answered, but you'll get a link to that answer.

Comment: @goldilocks I did not understand your first point can you please elaborate

Comment: If the pi is controlling a light via a relay, and that light has another wire on it on a switch, those two wires are probably continuous, so if you turn the switch on, the line out from the relay will be live, and that's what you could test.  **However,** this suddenly makes me wonder about the dangers of turning the switch on while the relay is already live; I think if they are ultimately all the same high voltage AC circuit that is okay, but do not trust me on that!  Also DC is easier for me to understand, so what I just said about the wire on the relay could be false.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks I will think on this, meanwhile if any one else can answer this completely please do thanks

Comment: I agree with tlhlngan, you don't need to step down 220V to 5v, because relay do it by separating 220v wire with control unit line. You could easily control relay with logic 1 or 0, so you can do it easily with simple program, like using Python or maybe if you want better control of your code you can using c. No, you don't need ic, if you want to control bulb, but I don't know if mechanical relay stable enough to endure load from your fan. Just be sure you don't messing up with wire 220ac and 5v.

Comment: There is nothing in the question specific to the Pi. It is a Q about sensing mains voltage.